# NodeJS 13 assert module missing methods like match

Tags: node.js

The [official documentation for assert](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/assert.html) lists many more methods than I am seeing in NodeJS 13.2.

```
const assert = require('assert');
assert.match('f01', /.\d\d/); // Exception 'TypeError: assert.match is not a function'
```

Why are things like `match()` missing?

[image: img]

Comment: You are looking at the docs for 13.14.0, but you have 13.2.0... So either refer to the docs of your version (13.2.0) which doesn't have `match`, or upgrade your version to 13.14.0 which does have `match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` method is missing in `Node.js v13.2`. [You can see the documentation for version 13.2 here.](https://nodejs.org/dist/v13.2.0/docs/api/assert.html)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js no longer supports `assert.match()`. Sorry!

A **quick fix** is to use the `regex.test()`, together with `assert.ok()` like this:

```
let html = "<html><body><h1>Welcome</h1>...</body></html>"; 
assert.ok(/<h1>Welcome<\/h1>/i.test(html), "Incorrect title");
```

For your example, try this:

```
assert.ok(/.\d\d/.test('f01'));
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It's there in NodeJS > 13.14
See https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

Comment: Looks like in version 13, the `match` method was missing, then in some later version, it was mysteriously returned back.